# How to determine key variables that influence sales trend using regression model (or a different model)

Tags: r, regression, multivariate-analysis, trend, lm

I have several clients that creates a sales trend. I'm trying to estimate which are the key clients that influence the most in this trend.

I'm trying to do this with a simple linear regression model in R and then assign coefficient values or the importance variable with varImp from caret package, but I'm not getting good answers as my model is a perfect fit.

The code I'm writing is the following:

```
df = data.frame(y_var = c(2762000, 574500, 125800, 634280, 43000, 175000, 2707248, 55200, 59500), 
                x_1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 584000, 0, 0), 
                x_2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2123248, 0, 0), 
                x_3 = c(0, 0, 0, 634280, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
                x_4 = c(2762000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 175000, 0, 0, 0), 
                x_5 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 43000, 0, 0, 55200, 59500), 
                x_6 = c(0, 574500, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
                x_7 = c(0, 0, 125800, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) 
                )
```

y_var is the sum of x_1:x_7 clients and each row represents the date of the sales trend.

What I'm trying to do next is to estimate a model in the form Y(t) = Beta1 * X_1(t) + ... + Beta7 * X_7(t) for t in period 1:T (in this example I have 9 periods only).

I want to estimate the clients that have the highest Beta as those should be my key clients influencing this trend. To do this I create a lm formula in R:

```
model = lm(y_var ~., data = df)
```

After running the lm fit is when I realized I did my approach wrong:

```
> summary(model)

Call:
lm(formula = y_var ~ ., data = df)

Residuals:
         1          2          3          4          5          6          7          8          9 
-8.279e-13 -1.767e-28  2.423e-27 -1.767e-28 -4.871e-11  1.307e-11  5.049e-29  1.755e-11  1.891e-11 

Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)
              Estimate Std. Error    t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -3.881e-11  4.163e-11 -9.320e-01     0.45    
x_1          4.636e+00  9.893e-17  4.686e+16   <2e-16 ***
x_2                 NA         NA         NA       NA    
x_3          1.000e+00  9.109e-17  1.098e+16   <2e-16 ***
x_4          1.000e+00  2.155e-17  4.641e+16   <2e-16 ***
x_5          1.000e+00  8.921e-16  1.121e+15   <2e-16 ***
x_6          1.000e+00  1.006e-16  9.944e+15   <2e-16 ***
x_7          1.000e+00  4.593e-16  2.177e+15   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 4.006e-11 on 2 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:      1, Adjusted R-squared:      1 
F-statistic: 1.048e+33 on 6 and 2 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

Warning message:
In summary.lm(model) : essentially perfect fit: summary may be unreliable
```

The coefficients don't behave as I expected (obviously I'm wrong) and what's worse is that x_2 variable that has significant revenue between my clients is giving me NA and if I try to use caret for the varImp it's still not good:

```
> caret::varImp(model)
         Overall
x_1 4.685881e+16
x_3 1.097853e+16
x_4 4.640589e+16
x_5 1.120952e+15
x_6 9.943821e+15
x_7 2.177428e+15
```

I know I'm getting *NA* in x_2 because it has a perfect correlation with x_1 (`with(df, cor(x_1, x_2))` returns 1) and any idea which would be the best way to tackle the key important clients for this solution in an automated way?

Thanks for your help!